# JRuby OpenSSL Error

Tags: rubygems, openssl, jruby

I am having problems configuring JRuby to work properly with OpenSSL.  Googling has revealed that this is a pretty common occurence, but none of the solutions I've read have worked for me.  Here is my setup:

- Ubuntu 9.10
- jruby 1.5.1
- jruby-openssl (0.7)

Here is the error:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'jruby/openssl/gem_only'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'openssl'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> OpenSSL::Digest::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER
NameError: uninitialized constant OpenSSL::Digest::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER
```

Interestingly, `require 'openssl'` returns true even if I don't have the jruby-openssl gem installed.  According to [this link](http://jruby.org/openssl), that shouldn't happen?

Trying to load the gem explictly with `require 'rubygems'` and `gem 'jruby-openssl'` doesn't help.

Comment: Similar setup for me too. (X)ubuntu 10.04 (x64), jruby 1.4.0, jruby-openssl 0.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are looking at the right constant?

```
$ ruby -v -r openssl -e 'p OpenSSL::Digest::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER'
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
-e:1: uninitialized constant OpenSSL::Digest::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER (NameError)

$ ruby -v -r openssl -e 'p OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER'
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
9470159

$ jruby -v -r openssl -e 'p OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER'
jruby 1.5.1 (ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 249) (2010-06-06 f3a3480) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_20) [x86_64-java]
9469999
```

Comment: Well, now that's interesting. But in my case, the error is coming from a gem, so I'm going to assume that at some point at least this was the correct constant.

Comment: @Matthew We are getting this error from the same gem in fact (Redcar).  There was a bug that caused this error for me.  Once that bug was fixed, I removed the .redcar folder, and reinstalled and everything was fine, so maybe you should give that a shot.

Comment: @dbyrne: Yea, it's fixed for me too. Still curious about the fix itself though. Might see if I can get Dan to post here about it.

Comment: @Matthew: Here for a description of the problem: http://groups.google.com/group/redcar-editor/browse_thread/thread/b8b1bfdbc8155b92#