# Jruby openssl circular dependency

Tags: jruby

I did a fresh install of jruby 1.6.2, and then wanted to install some gems.

I ran this command:

```
jruby -S gem install cucumber
```

And got this error message:

```
JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
LoadError: OpenSSL::SSL requires the jruby-openssl gem
                         (root) at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/jruby/openssl/autoloads/ssl.rb:8
                       use_ssl= at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/jruby/openssl/autoloads/ssl.rb:124
                 connection_for at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:267
                        request at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:349
               open_uri_or_path at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:306
                     fetch_path at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:181
                     load_specs at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:251
                     load_specs at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/maven_gemify.rb:72
                           list at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:224
                           each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1602
                           list at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:220
                           list at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/maven_gemify.rb:63
      find_matching_with_errors at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:143
      find_matching_with_errors at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/maven_gemify.rb:54
              fetch_with_errors at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:83
         find_gems_with_sources at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:108
  find_spec_by_name_and_version at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:212
                        install at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:244
                        execute at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:120
                           each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1602
                        execute at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:115
                         invoke at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/command.rb:278
                   process_args at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:133
                            run at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:103
                            run at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:63
                         (root) at /Users/Staffr02/Development/jruby-1.6.2/bin/gem:21
```

So then I tried this:

```
jruby -S gem install jruby-openssl
```

And I got the same error, which seemed a little odd. I'm running Mac OS 10.6.6.

I did some googling, and couldn't really find anything, except for a page that said this:

However, this breaks programs that use require 'openssl' as a test for whether openssl is available or not. Soap4r is one such program. In order to support this behavior, simply add

require 'jruby/openssl/gem_only'

So I tracked down the file that seemed to have the error (gem_runner.rb) and added the require line in there. I ran jruby -S gem install jruby-openssl again, and got this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Net::HTTP::OpenSSL
```

Has anyone else had this problem before? I don't understand what I did wrong! Are there some independent openssl settings that I should delete first?

Any guidance would be much appreciated - thanks,

Rebecca

Comment: Just to let any viewers know, I downloaded the gem and tried to manually install and got the same error.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045910/unable-to-install-rails-with-jruby and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261745/jruby-openssl-error